# Cross platform version of ntohl()? - C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, endianness

I am writing a cross platform client and in the archives that are extracted for use, it uses an IEEE 802.3 Ethernet CRC-32 checksum for each file. I run this check against all of the files like so:

```
if(s3d_meta_block.crc != 0x61580AC9)
{
    errorLog.writeError("File %i is not a valid file/ or is the directory", i);
}
```

It ends up failing on every one of the files and I have found it written elsewhere in similar clients with ntohl(0x61580AC9).

I am writing this on 64-bit Windows and would ideally like this to run on every platform without having to include "Winsock2.h" and the other libraries involved in reversing the endianess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ntohl() is included on many platforms and will/will not swap the bits as needed by your processors alignment. The only thing you may need in you code is #def's to include the right header files for this function (I've never seen an OS without it)

Comment: That def can probably rely on __WIN32__ being defined or not. If not, include <arpa/inet.h> instead of winsock.

Comment: @dbrank0 If you are going to post a good comment post an example ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish `ntohl` only swaps if byte ordering isn't big-endian. Alignment has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @moshbear Can you elaborate a bit more. So if I was to run ntohl, it would detect what kind of endianess it is and then only swap it if it needs it?

Comment: @Satchmo - `ntohl` *knows* the platform it is on, so it doesn't have to detect anything. On some systems it changes data, on others it doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: @SatchmoBrown Glibc uses gcc's __BYTE_ORDER macro to determine endianness. Take a look at http://pastebin.com/bKzkMzwr (be32toh is functionally identical to ntohl). If you want to be pedantic, then look at http://pastebin.com/ehh3ektT - they're identical. In any case, the behavior of ntohX is determined at compile time, based on endianness. If you read the POSIX spec, it will likely state that the exact behavior is implementation-defined (and it is).

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation. Looks easier than I thought.

Comment: @moshbear And your point is? I told the OP that? Ive worked with cross platform comm for 25 years - whats your experience in this field?